# How can I create a table with round edges and a style like a grid table?

Tags: css

I have tried many things to get round edges but it doesn't work. Here's the code I have so far:

```
<div style="border-radius: 5px;">
    <table style="margin-left: 10px; padding-right: 0px; width: 710px;border-collapse:collapse; border-radius: 5px;" 
    class="ui-widget-content">
        <tr class="ui-state-default">
            <th>abc</th>
            <th>def</th>
            <th>xxx</th>
            <th>xxx</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>a</th>
            <th>b</th>
            <th>c</th>
            <th>d</th>
        </tr>
    </table> 
</div>
```

What I really aim for is to have a table that looks like this: [grid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html)  Can anyone suggest how I could get the top panel, bottom panel and the rounded corners (css)?

Please note that I tried to mix in some jQuery UI theme classes. But these don't seem to help so I think they need removing. I just want a really simple implementation that looks like the grid in the example above.

Comment: What things have you tried? What happened when you did?

Comment: I tried the code above. I put in the border-radius on the table and also a div around that. But there were no rounded corners in my browser which is the latest firefox.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

Comment: After adding a background to the table element, your example has rounded borders. Could you please provide a JSFiddle.net with jQuery UI loaded and probably the theme you use?

Answer (score 0):

on which browsers the code you wrote above is not working???

The code you pasted above works for IE9 only, I think.

you should have some thing like this in your css :

```
  .roundedCorners{
      -webkit-border-radius: 10px;/*For Google Chrome*/
      -moz-border-radius: 10px;/*For Mozilla*/
      border-radius: 10px;/*Standard Specification*/
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code does work; however, you can not see it do to it not having a background colour. When I added "background-color: #f00;" I could see it perfectly fine. I also recommend following the code by X-Ware because this type of css is not ratify. Thus that code is used for fixing any compatibility issues that may come up in the future.

Remember, rounded corners do not work in IE6, IE7, IE8 or IE9. For this, I recommend [CSS3 Pie](http://css3pie.com/)

Comment: Border-radius does work in IE9. You should probably just show normal corners to your IE6-8 users. CSS3 Pie is quite heavy on performance and, after all, those rounded corners are probably not crucial to any of your users anyway.